# How to harvest all files in release bin and add some additional info for some executable in a Wix setup?

Tags: .net-core, wix

Up until today, we were listing all the specific files we want to be included in our wix setup:

```
        <Component Id="Some_Files" Guid="4DC25232-0B8D-4C16-ABC9-5BD3B45D0358" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
            <File Id="SomeService.dll" Name="SomeService.dll" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\SomeService.dll" />
            <!-- .... -->
        </Component>
```

but our solutions grows more and more and everytime we change a nuget package version, every time we add a library, we have to think to add a lot of files.

We would like to build a Visual studio SLNF especially tailored for the release(not the scope of this question) and then copy all its files into a Wix setup.

But we have some additional things to do for some files:
We have one windows service that we were setuping previously like this:

```
    <Component Id="Service" Guid="72044696-3E92-4928-BC6D-5A9C5FBB924A" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
        <File Id="Service.exe"
              Name="Service.exe"
              KeyPath="yes"
              Vital="no"
              Compressed="default"
              DiskId="1"
              Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\Service.exe" />
        <ServiceInstall Id="NewServiceInstall2" 
                Name="Service" 
                DisplayName="Service" 
                Type="ownProcess" 
                Interactive="no" 
                Start="auto" 
                Account="LocalSystem"
                ErrorControl="normal" 
                Vital="yes" />
                Wait="no" />-->
<ServiceControl Id="Uninstall" 
                Name="Service" 
                Stop="both" 
                Remove="uninstall" />
    </Component>
```

Or some shortcut/File association to generate:

```
  <Component Id="MyApp" Guid="B603887B-149F-4364-8305-EFB6CB6E2026" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
    <File Id="MyApp.exe" Name="MyApp.exe" KeyPath="yes" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\MyApp.exe" >
      <Shortcut Id="mnuVision" Directory="solutionMenu" Name="MyApp" Description="Launch the APP" WorkingDirectory="BIN" />
    </File>
    <ProgId Id="MyAppProject" Icon="MyApp.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes">
      <Extension Id="myapp" Advertise="yes">
        <Verb Id="Open" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;" />
      </Extension>
    </ProgId>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Component>
```

So before I rework everything and sees that it doesn't work, does somebody knows if it is possible and if it is, how to specify it without having duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Visual Studio integration (I call heat.exe directly in my build), but using [heat's -t parameter](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/overview/heat/) on its harvested output, you can do this kind of thing:

`transform.xslt` (derived from my production code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" exclude-result-prefixes="wix">
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- add ServiceInstall/ServiceControl specifically to Service.exe -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '\Service.exe')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:comment> transform.xslt </xsl:comment>
      <ServiceInstall
          Name="Service" 
          DisplayName="Service" 
          Type="ownProcess" 
          Interactive="no" 
          Start="auto" 
          Account="LocalSystem"
          ErrorControl="normal" 
          Wait="no" />
      <ServiceControl
          Name="Service" 
          Stop="both" 
          Remove="uninstall" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which should result in output like this:

```
<Component Id="Service.exe" Directory="somewhere" Guid="{someguid}">
    <File Id="Service.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="somewhere\Service.exe" />
    <!-- transform.xslt -->
    <ServiceInstall Name="Service" DisplayName="Service" Type="ownProcess" Interactive="no" Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Wait="no" />
    <ServiceControl Name="Service" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" />
</Component>
```

(The ids for your ServiceInstall/ServiceControl actions should be unnecessary)

Comment: I see, but how to match how the basic DLL that just needs to be included? Also, do you create one component per DLL?

Comment: Assuming you harvest a dir, creating one component per DLL is heat's default, yes. As long as it's also versioned properly, that shouldn't pose a problem. I don't know what you mean by matching the basic DLL? If you mean to leave it unmodified in the output, that's why the xpath expression in the template matches specifically Service.exe and nothing else.

Comment: I'm not highly familiar with XSLT, it goes way back. But if there is nothing "matching", it just copies the input to the output, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what the identity template does here. Just run heat to generate a wxs and experiment a bit.